# how to add a post api in kong and call it?

Tags: post, kong

suppose I have an api `http://host:port/api/v1/xxxx` with post method and accept the json body :

> {       "inputText":"travel to antartica from kochi"  }

how can i add the post api to kong and call it ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an API Object
 you need to fill the args (name: whatever, uris: /api/v1/xxxx , upstream_url: http://host:port/api/v1/xxxx ) Then you can call it using http://your_kong_service:8000/api/v1/xxxx